# Norm of an operator $T: l^1(\mathbb{N}) \to \mathbb{C}^2$

Tags: functional-analysis

I have an exercise where i need to find the norm of the following operator: Define $T: l^1(N)\to \mathbb{C}^2$ by $e_n \mapsto (n/(n+1), 0.5)$ if $n\leq 4$, or $e_n \mapsto (n/(n+1), 0)$ if $n \geq 5$. For this exercise we endow $\mathbb{C}^2$ with the supremum norm.
This is kind of a multiple choice question, so i have these possible answers: a) 1 b) 2 c) 0.25 d) None of the above. I thought about computing $\sup_{x\in l^1(\mathbb{N})} \Vert T(x) \Vert$ for $\Vert x \Vert =1$. If $x=e_n$ for some n then $\sup_{n \in \mathbb{N}}\Vert e_n \Vert = \sup_{n\in \mathbb{N}}n/(n+1)=1$ which would give us answer a), but i don't think i can assume that the $e_n$ are the only elements with norm 1. I would be very happy if anybody could help me, thanks in advance!

Comment: $\{e_i\}_{i\in \mathbb N}$ is not basis. So How we extend $T$ to whole space?

Comment: $e_n$ is supposed to be the sequence which sonsists only of zeros, except for the n-th entry, where it has 1. Why is this not a basis? But this is the only thing we know about this operator in this exercise

Comment: It is not a basis

Comment: Why is it not a basis?

Comment: $\{\frac {1}{i^2}\}_{i\in \mathbb N}$ Is not In span. Or any Banach space can not have countably infinite basis.

Comment: Because there is no way express the sequence $(1,1/4, 1/9,\ldots,1/n^2,\ldots)$, which is in $l^1(\mathbb N)$ as a sum of finitely many scaled $e_n$.

Comment: Your operator is given by $$T(x)=\left (\sum_{n=1}^\infty {n\over n+1}x_n, \sum_{n=1}^40.5 x_n\right )$$ In order to calculate the norm it suffices to consider $x_n\ge 0.$ Observe that ${n\over n+1}\ge 0.5$ hence it suffices to consider the first coordinate, i.e. $\sum_{n=1}^\infty {n\over n+1}x_n,$ for $x_n\ge 0.$

Comment: @RyszardSzwarc How can we  determine operator uniquely from given information?